# How to extract / edit hyperlinks from powerpoint documents using Apache POI?

Tags: java, xml, hyperlink, apache-poi, powerpoint

I was curious if anybody has found a way to edit a hyperlink inside of a powerpoint document using Apache POI? I've been looking through the documentation and haven't made any real progress. My goal is to be able to see a hyperlink in a slide (i.e. "Google") that is a hyperlink to "http://google.com/" and edit it to something like "Yahoo" (which links to http://yahoo.com). My current way of going through the document is shape by shape (slide by slide). I'm not sure if there's a way to do this by analyzing the XML perhaps? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the [tests for XSLF](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/TestXSLFHyperlink.java) and update your question ...

Comment: There's a lot of great stuff in that link for creating hyperlinks and adding them to a powerpoint. Nothing there (from what I see) shows a way to extract or edit an already existing hyperlink.

Comment: `testRead()` shows how to get a `XSLFHyperlink` and in `testCreate()` you see that `setAddress()` can be used to change the link. What else do you need?

Comment: I'm quite blind. Thank you so much haha.